# Webpack to "ignore" some entrypoints

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack to build my front end components.

I have some React components which need classic webpack bundling, though I also have some vanilla JS files.

Those latter files are independent, so they won't get imported from React files. From my understanding, they need to be defined as entrypoints, so that Webpack reads and processes them. So far, so good.

The trouble is that I'd like Webpack to load them with Babel, and that's all, only give me back the JS file processed through Babel, I'm not interested in a bundle for these files.

Is it possible to do that? Only get the result of the babel loader, and not produce a bundle for some entrypoints?

Maybe I shouldn't use Webpack at all for these files?
Or maybe I should just set these bundles as 'library' so that I can reach them from the HTML pages?

What do you think guys?

Thanks by advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

depends on how easy it is to find these files. I have a project that has similar requirement. What I have done is:

1/ put the vanilla js file in `third_party/lib/`

2/ import/require them in my current project

3/ set up my `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.export = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test : /.js$/,
      exclude : /node_modules|third_party/,
      loaders : ['babel-loader' /* other loaders? */],
    },{
      test : /third_party.*?\.js$/,
      use: [{
        loader : 'babel-loader' // or other loaders
      },{
        loader: 'file-loader'
        options: {
          name : '[path][name].[ext]',
          outputPath : 'dist/third_party'
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

oh, you will need to `npm i --save-dev file-loader`

edit: I should clarify that this will bundle the vanilla js file as separate files to your main bundle, so you will have to import them by script tags yourself in your html file. (or if they were worker files, called by your script)

Comment: The issue is: I don't want to import it from a React entrypoint. The vanilla JS file is standalone and not needed in React. I just want it to be processed by webpack... But I think I should probably not do this with webpack (since it is suppose to package things in bundle), rather, I should write a custom NPM script that will do the job!